# XCode4 lock nib file

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

I have a strange issues.

I have a nib file with some view inside and before yesterday all work fine for me.

Today I try to add a view in my nib file but I cannot! When I release a view inside the nib I can see an padlock overlay in the middle of XCode windows..

I changed all View "Lock" propeties in "Nothing" for all the view and the File Owner but didn't work again.

What's wrong!?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem and fixed it by selecting the view (or the locked element, a label in my case) and then press the *Reset Locking Controls* under the *Interface Builder Document* section in the *File Inspector* window.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Was not a problem... it was yet another annoying Apple "feature" :-)  In Xcode 4.41 the window is now called "Identity"

Answer (score 1):

The 'Localization Locking' Option ('Reset Locking Control')is here (Xcode 5)

Menu: Editor-> Localization Locking -> Reset Locking Control !
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19666458/1656395

Answer (score 0):

In terminal use following code

```
sudo chown -R <UserId> <ProjectFolder>/*
```