# Where is located the Unlocking Xib files option 'Reset Locking Control' (for 'Localization Locking') in xCode 5 for edition

Tags: localization, locking, interface-builder, xib, xcode5

Where is located the 'Localization Locking' Option ('Reset Locking Control') for Interface builder 5 in xCode 5?

- In Xcode 4.6.3 I have some xib files locked using the 'Localization Locking' feature (All properties) in interface builder 4.6 to not accidentally changes the Layouts…
- After opening my project with xCode 5.1 it updated all the xib files to be only opened by Interface builder 5.

Now I want to revert the 'Interface Builder Option' to Open with Interface Builder 4.6 BUT I CANT SAVE THE CHANGES as the files are locked and I can't open those files with xCode 4.6 any More to unlock THEM!

Also, I can't DO ANY Modifications to this files in xCode 5 (Interface Builder 5) because there locked!

edit: 'It IS located in Menu: Editor-> Localization Locking -> Reset Locking Control'!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It IS located in Menu: Editor-> Localization Locking -> Reset Locking Control !